# Initializing std::vector with ranges library

Tags: c++, c++20

I would like to initialize `std::vector` with a range of consecutive integers without typing all of them, something like a second line, which doesn't compile, in this code snippet:

```
  std::vector<int> a{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::vector<int> b{std::ranges::iota_view(0, 5)};  // ERROR!
```

Of course, I would greatly prefer:

```
  std::vector<int> b{0:5};
```

but this is not scheduled before C++41 standard. Any ideas how to do it in C++20?

Comment: Do you have any specific restrictions that would preclude setting them in a loop? Requiring it at compile time doesn't make much sense as the storage space doesn't exist, then.

Comment: Whats wrong with 'std::vector<int> b(5); std::iota(b.begin(), b.end(), 0)'?

Comment: @Cortex: Because it value-initializes the array first.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I like concise notation and prefer to avoid imperative code when possible.

Comment: @PaulJurczak: "*prefer to avoid imperative code when possible*" It's C++; by default, it is an imperative programming language. It can have some functional-like stuff bolted onto it, but at the bottom, it's just imperative programming.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm actively looking for `some functional-like stuff bolted onto it`

Comment: @Cortex `0:5` or `0,5` is completely lost and reversed in your example.

Comment: @PaulJurczak what?

Comment: @PaulJurczak '.. range of consecutive integers without typing all of them' that is the definition of std::iota, I get the value initialization, but is this really performance / memory critical?

Comment: @Cortex It's not mainly for performance. My main goal here is readability.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Well std::vector has 9 constructors, but none of them do what you seek. That aside, std::iota is literally made for readability, any programmer who sees it will instantly know the contents of your vector.

Comment: How about the iterator constructor? `auto v = std::views::iota(0, 5); auto b = std::vector(v.begin(), v.end());`

Comment: @J.Willus That's probably the best we've got in C++, but it's embarrassingly wordy compared to many other languages.

Comment: @J.Willus That's not guaranteed to work: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93651

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you’re looking for is

```
auto b=std::ranges::to<std::vector>(std::ranges::iota_view(0, 5));
```

Unfortunately, that [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1206r1.pdf) missed C++20 simply because there wasn’t time to review its wording (after a previous version that added the constructor you tried was found unworkable).  Hopefully it’ll be merged—and implemented—early in the C++23 cycle.