# Range concept and containers constructors

Tags: c++, containers, c++20, c++-concepts

I was checking C++20 Range Library on en.cppreference.com. Roughly speaking, it looks like to be compliant to the `Range` concept a type needs to have `begin` and `end` iterator accessors. This should make every container in STL be compliant to the `Range` concept. However, when I checked some containers constructors I saw that they still have the overload taking explicitly `begin` and `end` iterators as input, but no overload taking simply just one range object.

Is it because en.cppreference.com is not yet updated, or is it standardized that we will not be able to construct a container using just range?

Comment: I don't see anything in C++20 that actually added an overloaded constructor to containers that takes a Range parameter.

Comment: I found https://wg21.link/P1206r0 and its revision https://wg21.link/P1206r1 that propose that constructors taking ranges or a new `ranges::to<container_type>(range);` function. Since these exist, I assume nothing is in the standards yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializing std::vector with ranges library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841418/initializing-stdvector-with-ranges-library)

Comment: As I recall, there were kinks to work out and not enough time before C++20. You could try looking through trip reports for a better explanation.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, thanks. Missed opportunity to not have a dedicated ctor already in C++20 though.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: They tried that and found that it didn’t work well—constructor overload sets are hard.

Comment: @DavisHerring I actually tried in trunk gcc, I define two constructor overloads for the same `struct` one that takes an `std::integral` and another one which takes `std::ranges::range`, and they work perfectly fine. This means that in theory they could have disambiguated the container constructor which takes an allocator type to the one which takes a range type. :/