# In C++ STL algorithms, get index of a value inside lambda function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++14, thrust

I wanted to get the index of the value(s) inside `std` algorithm's lambda function. So that, I can perform computation on the values based on the index. I am able to get an index with `for_each` function. However, I am not able to do so for `std::adjacent_difference`. Can you help me understand why I am not able to extract the index in other algorithms that use binary op? My attempt is to try in a generic fashion that work on a parallel (thrust) setting as well. So, did not seek a method of `static` count'ing.

```cpp
//~~~START:Mon, 04-Oct-2021, 13:03:46 IST
//~~~Author:Rajesh Pandian M | mrprajesh.co.in
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
void print(const auto &data){
  std::copy(data.begin(),data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << '\n';
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  std::vector<int> data={0,2,3,5,10,11};
  std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&data](int const& value) {
    int idx = &value - &data[0];
    std::cout<< "idx: " << idx << '\n';
  });

  print(data);

  std::vector<int> result(data.size());
  std::adjacent_difference(data.begin(), data.end(), result.begin(),
    [&data]( const int& value2, const int& value1) {
      int idx = &value2 - &data[0];
      std::cout<< "idx: " << idx << '\n';
      return value2-value1; //Some expression involving index, values[1,2]
    });

  print(result);

  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
idx: 0
idx: 1
idx: 2
idx: 3
idx: 4
idx: 5
0 2 3 5 10 11 
idx: -102822055
idx: -102822055
idx: -102822055
idx: -102822055
idx: -102822055
0 2 1 2 5 1
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65022698/10107454) could be of interest.

Comment: As this question is tagged with Thrust: Thrust provides some smart iterators to solve this problem. There is a `thrust::counting_iterator` similar to what was implemnted in the question I linked above. There is also the `thrust::zip_iterator` to combine the counting iterator with e.g. the iterator to a container when the algorithm doesn't take enough inputs.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference/adjacent_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference):

> First, creates an accumulator `acc` whose type is InputIt's value type, initializes it with `*first`, and assigns the result to `*d_first`. Then, for every iterator `i` in `[first + 1, last)` in order, creates an object `val` whose type is InputIt's value type, initializes it with `*i`, computes `val - acc` (until C++20) `val - std::move(acc)` (since C++20) (overload (1)) or `op(val, acc)` (until C++20) `op(val, std::move(acc))` (since C++20) (overload (3)), assigns the result to `*(d_first + (i - first))`, and move assigns from `val` to `acc`.

In short: The binary operator is called via `op(val,acc)` and neither `val` nor `acc` are elements of the container.

If you need the index you can populate a `std::vector<std::pair<size_t,int>>` such that `data[ i ].first == i`.

Comment: > `val` nor `acc` are elements of the container.
Oh, I see. Thanks. That helps in my understanding.